# Can't get values from image crop using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

I'm using [JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/) to crop an image in a Flask app I'm developing.  I'm trying to grab the coordinates generated by the crop tool.  But when I use `request.form.get` to get the values it just returns None.  When inspecting the HTML code in the browser it's also showing now value contained even though it's displayed.  I'm pretty sure I'm missing some key information for how this works under the hood.  So I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.

Here is the relevant code from my app.  I can easily provide more information if needed:

Edit: Adding the flask code from routes.py

Edit #2: I figured out what was going on but I still don't quite understand why.  It all had to do with where I was placing my HTML code block that holds the coordinate elements.  I originally had the coord form outside of the form that other form I have on the page.  Due to some testing I discovered that I wasn't getting any data returned from the coord form but I was with the other form.  So once I placed coord into the above form I started getting data returned.  I'm unsure why this is the case since my knowledge of HTML is limited.

```
def index():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        display = DisplayForm()
        x1 = request.form.get('outX1')
        y1 = request.form.get('outY1')
        return render_template('display.html', title=('Preview'), display=display, x1=x1, y1=y1)
    return render_template('index.html', title=('Home'), form=form)
```

---

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h1>{{ ('Test Bed') }}</h1>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <div class="row">          
        <form class="form-inline center-block" action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="input-group">
                <label id="browsebutton" class="btn btn-default input-group-addon" for="my-file-selector">
                    {{ form.input_file(id="my-file-selector") }}
                    Browse...
                </label>
                {{ form.test_input(id="test_input", readonly="readonly")}}
            </div>
            {{ form.submit(class_="btn btn-primary") }}
            <br>
            <br>
            <form id="coords" class="coords">
                <div class="inline-labels">
                    <label>X1 {{ form.outX1(id="outX1", size="4")}}</label>
                    <label>Y1 {{ form.outY1(id="outY1", size="4")}}</label>
                    <label>X2 {{ form.outX2(size="4")}}</label>
                    <label>Y2 {{ form.outY2(size="4")}}</label>
                    <label>H {{ form.outW(size="4")}}</label>
                    <label>W {{ form.outH(size="4")}}</label>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img id="output_image"/>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <br>
{% endblock %}
```

---

```
$(document).on('change', '#browsebutton :file', function() {
    var input = $(this),
    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
    filename = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, filename]);
});

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#browsebutton :file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, filename) {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find('.text'),
        fileName = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : filename;
        if( input.length ) {
            } else {
                if( fileName ) {
                    document.getElementById("test_input").value = fileName;
                }
        }
        var input2 = event.target;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            var dataURL = reader.result;
            var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
            output.src = dataURL;

            var jcrop_api;

            $('#output_image').Jcrop({
                aspectRatio: 2/2.25,
                onChange:   showCoords,
                onSelect:   showCoords,
                onRelease:  clearCoords
                },function(){                    
                    jcrop_api = this;}
                );

            $('#coords').on('change','input',function(e){                
                var x1 = $('#outX1').val(),
                    x2 = $('#outX2').val(),
                    y1 = $('#outY1').val(),
                    y2 = $('#outY2').val();
                jcrop_api.setSelect([x1,y1,x2,y2]);
              });

            function showCoords(c){                
                $('#outX1').val(c.x);
                $('#outY1').val(c.y);
                $('#outX2').val(c.x2);
                $('#outY2').val(c.y2);
                $('#outW').val(c.w);
                $('#outH').val(c.h);
            }

            function clearCoords(){
                $('#coords input').val('');
            }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input2.files[0]);        
    });    
});
```

Comment: Where are you using `request.form.get`?

Comment: @showdev Sorry, I'm calling it from my routes.py.  I'll add that to my main post.